# Fechar jar programaticamente

Tags: java, jar

Atualmente tenho um programa JAVA(principal), que a partir dele chama outro programa JAVA (filho)... isso está Ok.. porém quando eu fecho o programa principal, quero também fechar o programa filho.

Já tentei:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID **NOMEDOPROGRAMA**");
```

Mas não funcionou...

Comment: O `taskkill /PID` espera o `pid` do programa, e não seu nome. Você poderia usar `/IM` para passar o nome, mas o problema é que o nome do programa no caso de programas java é sempre java.exe (ou javaw.exe). Você vai acabar matando o filho e o pai junto. Como você está fazendo para lançar o processo filho?

Comment: Ah consegui resolver... estava chamando o jar pelo Runtime mesmo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando se cria o processo com o método `exec()` é retornada uma instância de [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html). Então você pode guardar essa referência e destruí-la posteriormente com o método [`destroy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy%28%29).

Exemplo:

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("**NOMEDOPROGRAMA**");
...
p.destroy();
```

Comment: Obrigado! Não tinha prestado atenção! hehehe